# Sending HTML emails with sendgrid results in bad request

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid-api-v3

In a web application we have emails stored inside a database table. We pull these from the database, replace placeholders and send the email.

I am trying to use the web api /v3 of Sendgrid and I am encountering an issue.

Here is an example of how I am preparing my email to send:

```
var sent = false;
try
{
    var apiAddress = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiAddress);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer SG.snip");
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    var content = "<p>simple html comment with nothing complex</p>";
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{ \"categories\" :[\"cat1\"],\"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\":\"me@domain.com\"}],\"subject\": \"test email\"}],\"from\": {\"email\": \"email@domain.com\"},\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/html\",\"value\": \"<html>" + content + "</html>\"}]}";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    sent = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    sent = false;
}
```

This one sends fine, but when my content is complex, the API returns 400 BAD REQUEST and the email is not sent.

The email I am having trouble with has quotes inside it, for example here is a condensed version of the email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body>hi</body></html>
```

If I escape the quotes with a backslash it works fine. Do I have to go through the whole HTML escaping every quote?